# Vue3: changing a normal object causes rerender

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In the following code `state` is just a normal object but changing its prop: `message` (again, just a normal prop) causes a rerender. Why?

```js
const App = {
  setup() {
    const name = Vue.ref("");

    Vue.watch(name, () => state.message = `Hello ${name.value}`);

    const state = {
      name,
      message: "Welcome stranger"
    };
    return state;
  }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  name: <input v-model="name" /> <br/> message: {{ message }}
</div>
```

Comment: Because you are changing `name` ref (through `v-model`)

Comment: so what you're saying is that Vue batches updates hence it waits for all the watcher handlers etc to fire before rendering so it renders just once (on `name` change) and picking up the changes to `message` are just a happy coincidence? In other words, Vue doesn't really rerender on `message` change?

Comment: Vue instance watches the Virtual DOM. When we modify some property, Vue instance re-creates the Virtual DOM and checks for differences with the "Old" Virtual DOM. If it is different then it only updates that particular part in "real" DOM.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#effect-flush-timing

Answer (score 0):

As @MichalLevý pointed out, Vue doesn't really watch or rerender on `state.message` change. The change in `message` is only reflected in the DOM because of batching changes in response to `name` change.

This can be shown by just changing `state.message` in a timer handler. There's no rerender.

```js
const App = {
  setup() {
    const name = Vue.ref("");

    Vue.watch(name, () => state.message = `Hello ${name.value}`);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      state.message = "only message changed";
    }, 2000);

    const state = {
      name,
      message: "Welcome stranger"
    };
    return state;
  }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  name: <input v-model="name" /> <br/> message: {{ message }}
</div>
```